# How can I justify that the following function is continuous?

Tags: integration, continuity

$f\colon [0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function.

$$g(x) := \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{1+t^2} \,dt$$

I known that since $f$ is integrable, its indefinite integral is continuous by the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus. But I don't think the composite of integrable functions is integrable ($f$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$), and I need this to complete a step in a proof.

Comment: The composite isn't but the sum/product/division (provided not equal to zero) are.  Actually I think the composite is as a well,... well, maybe not integrable but continuous I think.

Comment: Oh ok thanks @fleablood!

Comment: There's a theorem that states that the composition of a continuous function over an integrable one is also integrable.